# Ratio of densities and expectation (related to Girsanov theorem).

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, stochastic-processes

If we define $$Z(\beta(t_1), \cdots, \beta(t_n)) := \frac{p(x(t_1), \cdots, x(t_n))}{p(\beta(t_1), \cdots, \beta(t_n))}$$ where $\beta$ is a brownian motion, $X$ is a stochastic process, and $p$ is the respective densities.
How come we have for any $h$ $$E(h(\beta(t_1), \cdots, \beta(t_n))Z(\beta(t_1), \cdots, \beta(t_n)))=E(h(x(t_1), \cdots, x(t_n))) ?$$

Comment: $E(\varphi(X)) = \int \varphi(x)f_X(x) dx$ so if $\varphi(x) = g(x) / f_X(x)$ then you have $E(\varphi(X)) = \int g(x) dx.$

Comment: (Just to clarify my previous comment, you do require $\varphi f_X = g$ a.e. so $f_X$ should be $> 0$ a.e. on the support of $g.$ This is the case when $f_X > 0$ everywhere as in the normal density.)